# How to encode arbitrary string for request in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8

I have  a string like that:  "abcde 李".  It can be any string with non latin characters.

I want to encode it to use in request, so it will be "abcde %E6%9D%8E" and can be used for http.request.

I have tried this:

```
str.toString("utf-8");
```

or

```
var buffer = new Buffer(str);
str = buffer.toString('utf-8');
```

but none of them work.  what is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string is already UTF-8.  It looks like you're trying to escape it for use in an [HTTP query string](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/querystring.html), so try this:

```javascript
var qs = require('querystring');
qs.escape('abcde 李'); // => 'abcde%20%E6%9D%8E'
```

Comment: You are the man!!!! I am always confused how to deal with encoding and escaping.. thanks. :)

Comment: In this case, what is the difference between qs.escape and encodeURI?

Comment: @Kelvin: there is effectively no difference for this example.  The node.js docs for [`querystring.escape(...)`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_escape) even note that the function exists primarily so that it can be overridden.  Using [`encodeURI(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) should yield the same result.

Comment: escape("abcde 李") == "abcde%20%u674E" ... encodeURI("abcde 李") == "abcde%20%E6%9D%8E"